# insert data in single query

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, odata

I have 2 tables like

```
VendorProduct vp = new VendorProduct
            {
                VendorPartNo = txtVdrPartNoOrg10.Value
            };
```

And

```
Product p = new Product
            {
                MfgPartNo = lbMfgPartNoOrg10.Text,
                Description = txtDesOrg10.Text,
                Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeightOrg10.Value),
                VendorProducts = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<VendorProduct>() { vp }
            };
```

How to **`Insert`** data into these tables something like

```
DataContext.AddObject("Product", p);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

How to set Links??

Comment: Looks like your trying to find an Object Relational Mapper (ORM). Take a look at Microsoft's Entity Framework for a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907